# solr facet counts not correct with stats and group option

Tags: solr, range, facet

I am using solr search for products-search on our web page. Since now, all works fine.
But while implementing a price slider, to filter actual results by pricerange, I'm stuck with the following issue:

There is no way to exclude filters for the stats option, same way as it is possible on facets. I use stats for getting the overall min- and max-price, no matter what price range is selected (on the slider) and which category is selected on actual search.

So best way to get this values is to exclude the range-filter on stats select, otherwise there will be max- and min-price just for the actual (ranged) result.

exclude a filter on facets (works on solr 4.4):

```
...&fq={!tag=cat}categories:Electronics/Computers&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=cat}categories&...
```

But using this for stats is not possible (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3177)

So then I tried using a group select as suggested on that called page. 
my solr call looks like this:

```
fq={!tag=cat}categories:Electronics/Computers&facet=true&
facet.field={!ex=cat}categories_raw&
facet.prefix=Electronics&stats=true&stats.field=minPrice&
stats.field=maxPrice&stats.field=vat&group=true&group.query=minPrice:[* TO 20]
maxPrice:[0 TO *]&group.main=true
```

All fine. I get the correct stats result and the correct result-count having applied the pricerange-filter. .... EXCEPT the problem, that the facet counts now were wrong, as I did not apply the price range filter.

I know there is a group.facet option, as I also tried. But using that group.facet I need to use a group.field on which the results are based on. In my opinion, usually I need to use the price-field as group.field (group.field=price).

But we do have two price fields on our products (min and max-price). I tried to set them both as group.field parameter, but still get the wrong facet-counts.

It looks like I am just a small step away from the correct solution, but I don't get it.

Comment: I found out, that there is an option to tell the facets counting the items from the group-select:

This is how it is explained in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing:

**group.truncate | true/false | If true, facet counts are based on the most relevant document of each group matching the query. Same applies for StatsComponent. Default is false. <!> Solr3.4 Supported from Solr 3.4 and up.*

But this setting does not have any effect on my select....